Meaning of link up
What does "link up" mean in sports context?

57 min: Arsenal 1 Man Utd 0
Odegaard and Saka link up after a driving run through the middle from Partey and Saka is played in behind United’s back three to shoot low. Onana goes down to save at his left post but Saka was offside in any case.


It's the standard dictionary meaning: form a connection/partnership, join together.

Please stop downvoting sports terms. A lot of OPs love sports and have a right to ask these question. [grrh]
